# azure cosmos maximum value of partitions key

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a app that save a lot of data, and I need to desing de collections a partitions keys. I need to known, Which is the maximum partition key into a collection? and What is the maximum number of documents into the partition key that I´d save?## Heading ##

Answer (score 0):

> Which is the maximum partition key into a collection?

AFAIK, there's no limit on number of partitions you can have in a collection. It would depend on the size of the collection but you can always raise a support request and get the size of collection increased.

> What is the maximum number of documents into the partition key that
>   I´d save?

Currently the maximum size of a partition is 10GB. Thus the number of documents you can put in a collection would depend on the size of the documents you store. Since the maximum size of a document can be 2MB (Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-api-resources#documents), you can have a minimum of 5120 documents assuming all of your documents are 2MB in size.

Comment: Not sure the "2MB, 5K document" example is realistic. At least, not something I've ever seen (and is often a signal of an unbounded-array situation, storing an ever-growing list of subdocuments within a document). If, instead, the average document size was 1K (a normalized value used in explaining RU costs, in the docs), you'd then have room for closer to 10 million documents per logical partition.

Comment: Agreed @DavidMakogon.